# Embeddings of disks into Euclidean space

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, h-principle

What are the smooth embeddings $D^n \hookrightarrow D^{2n}$ so that $\partial D^n \hookrightarrow \partial D^{2n}$, up to smooth isotopy (which can move the boundary of the disk)? This question might be too difficult in low-dimensions, $n = 2$, but maybe the answer is known in high-dimensions, $n \ge 3$. Let me know point out that Haefliger constructed different embeddings of $S^3 \hookrightarrow S^6$, which suggest that there are different embeddings $D^3 \hookrightarrow D^6$.

Comment: It seems to me there are just way too many smooth knotted $D^2$'s in $D^4$. Take any tame $2$-knot $S^2 \to S^4$, let $p$ be a point in the image. Scoop out a ball neighborhood of $p$ from $S^4$ to get $(D^2, \partial D^2) \to (D^4, \partial D^4)$. This is a knotted $2$-disk in $D^4$ whose boundary is an unknot $S^1$ in $S^3$. (Edit: Ah, that's why you want high dimensions)

Comment: I think it's unlikely there will be an $h$-principle calculation here. The continuous sheaf $\mathrm{Emb}(-, N)$ is highly nonlinear, whose "first derivative" is $\mathrm{Imm}(-, N)$. There are meaningful ways to define the higher derivatives, and it's a difficult theorem of Weiss-Klein-Goodwillie that for $m \leq n - 3$, $\mathrm{Emb}(-, N^n)$ on $M^m$ is analytic in the sense that the appropriate Taylor tower converges. This in theory solves the problem, but the individual terms are difficult to compute. See Goodwillie and Weiss, "Embeddings from the point of view of immersion theory".

Comment: @BalarkaSen Do you have concrete examples of non-isotopic disks in high dimensions?

Comment: You have mentioned that Haefliger constructed embeddings $S^3 \to S^6$. Simply take a point on the image and scoop out a ball neighborhood to get an embedding $(D^3, \partial D^3) \to (D^6, \partial D^6)$ like I mentioned above... if this was isotopic to the standard embedding, you could glue in the ball throughout the isotopy (since the boundary is kept fixed) to get that Haefliger's embedding is isotopic to the standard embedding, contradiction. It's the same thing I said for $2$-knots.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Sorry, I should have clarified, I allow the boundary of the disk to move during the isotopy. Otherwise, yes: this Haefliger example would show that the resulting disks are not isotopic via an isotopy that fixes their boundary.

Comment: Even so, the map on the boundary is an embedding $S^2 \to S^5$. Any two such embeddings are isotopic; so one can "reverse" the effect of the isotopy of the disk, and then glue a ball.

Comment: I suppose that needs some sort of an argument. Here's what I can think of: Choose a homotopy between the embeddings and consider its movie $S^2 \times I \to S^5 \times I$, $(x, t) \mapsto (f_t(x), t)$, which can be made transverse to itself and thus an immersion with clean double points. The total intersection number is $0$ as the map is homotopic to the trivial embedding, so the double points can be paired and then Whitney tricked to resolve it to an embedding $S^2 \times I \to S^5 \times I$. This shows the embeddings are concordant. Apply Theorem 1.2 in Haefliger's paper.